# How to enclose text within [cdata]...[!cdata] using PHP?

Tags: php, string, string-concatenation, cdata

I'm getting a text in a variable as follows:

```
$text = 'This is a code snippet';
```

Now I want to enclose the above text within [cdata]...[!cdata].

The output of echo $text should be like below:

```
[cdata]This is a code snippet[!cdata]
```

How should I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: use `$text = '[cdata]'.$text.'[!cdata]';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$text = 'This is a code snippet';
$text = '[cdata]'.$text.'[!cdata]';
echo $text;
```

Comment: If this is supposed to have any real world usage, I would be concerned about `$text = "[!cdata]";`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$text = "This is a code snippet";
$text = "[cdata]{$text}[!cdata]";
echo $text;
```